# Cytoscape GEM File Creating Unlabeled Square Nodes Instead Of Labeled Circle Nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I have been using Cytoscape's EnrichmentMap application for a few weeks, creating GEM files in g:Profiler and visualizing the results with EnrichmentMap. All files I created were working until today. I have generated 8 GEM files for different gene lists in g:Profiler, and 4 of them create the proper network visualization of the graph with labeled circular nodes with edges connecting them when clicking "Build". The other 4 create a network of edges connecting red rectangles that are unlabeled. I am unable to add a picture to Stack Overflow to show this or the GEM files.

I am using Cytoscape 3.8.2 on Windows 10. There are no errors upon creation of the network visualization.

I inspected the GEM files between those that worked and those that did not work, and they did not show any noticeable differences. Any advice would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about your issues.  Typically, the "red nodes" mean that a Visual Style wasn't loaded.  You can easily fix that in Cytoscape by just selecting the style.  Take a look for a style called "EM1_Visual_Style" (it might be some other number than 1) and select it.  Hopefully that will bring your style back.

-- scooter

Comment: Hi Scooter! Thank you very much for your response! Unfortunately, the style was already "EM1_Visual_Style" which produced the unlabeled red squares. An interesting thing is that when I hover the mouse over the squares, the term still shows (e.g. cytoskeletal protein binding).